# What is wrong with my Conditional Split in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, conditional-split

I have created an `SSIS` package which extracts data from an Excel file and outputs the results into a table in my database.

As this package will be run on a daily basis, I need to extract only those records which has been input on the day. Thus, I have added a `Conditional Split` in `Data Flow`.

When I run the "debug" in Visual Studio, my package runs fine and it shows as a "success". However, no records appear in my SQL Server Table.

I am assuming that I am doing something wrong at the "Conditional Split" level.

My "Condition" in the "Conditional Split Transformation Editor" looks as follows:

```
date == GETDATE()
```

"date" refers to a column in the Excel File where dates have been entered in the following format: 2021-06-24

I would appreciate some help to identify the problem.

Comment: `GETDATE()` returns a `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`, so is accurate to 1/300th of a second. I *doubt* the data you are importing was generated at the exact time you tried to import it. Likely you need to convert the value to a `DT_DATE` before you compare.

Comment: Data don't have time component in it. Only YYYY-MM-DD. I mean the date column has been formatted in Excel as such.

Comment: *"Data don't have time component in it."* But `GETDATE()` **does**. `2021-06-24 17:24:59:693` and `2021-06-24` are *not* the same value.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. date == (DT_DBDATE)(GETDATE()) did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to "Larnu" for pointing me in the right direction.

This is what was needed in my case:

```
date == (DT_DBDATE)(GETDATE())
```